# Git: automatic clean-up?

Tags: git, garbage-collection, git-gc

In the past, one had to invoke `git gc` from time to time. I've read now, that latest Git versions should perform the cleanup automatically. Is this correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To an extent...

From the documentation at http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-gc.html

Pertaining to git gc --auto....

> With this option, git gc checks whether any housekeeping is required;
>   if not, it exits without performing any work. Some git commands run
>   git gc --auto after performing operations that could create many loose
>   objects.

So it depends on the commands you are running.

Answer (score 5):

You can setup a `cron` task as explained here: http://minhajuddin.com/2011/12/09/gc-your-git-repositories-automatically-with-a-cron-task

As the `git help gc` says: users are encouraged to run this task on a regular basis within each repository to maintain good disk space utilization and good operating performance.

Some git commands may automatically run `git gc`. If you know what you’re doing and all you want is to disable this behavior permanently without further considerations, just do:

```
git config --global gc.auto 0
```

Also, you can configure prune behaviour:

```
git config gc.pruneexpire "30 days"
```